# HTML - Layout With Images

Tags: html

How do I make the image fit the div size? I wanted something like this https://www.quackit.com/html/templates/download/bootstrap/portfolio-2-column/index.html#

Atm is huge: https://i.gyazo.com/ae6d8873c56931cb9972b4c777799dc9.jpg

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 portrait" >
    <h2>Gaming</h2>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/Battlefield1.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <p>
        Gaming is the act of playing games.
    </p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("Gaming","Gaming")" > Take me to Gaming &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Get more libraries</h2>
    <p>NuGet is a free Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("Hot","Memes")" >Take me to Memes &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Web Hosting</h2>
    <p>You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features and price for your applications.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("Programming","Programming")" >Take me to Programming &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using stylesheets because it's laid out properly in there and you're using CSS class names. Without the CSS it's hard to say what your problem is.

If you have no CSS on the image then that's an issue. If the image is that large and `overflow` is set to visible on the div, then that's why you're seeing the huge image. I would give the image a class like so:

```
.class {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This would make sure it's no larger than full width of the `div`. If you just want to make sure it's ALWAYS 100% then use `width` instead of `max-width` however it will end up scaling the image if you use `width`.

Then of course you'd want to add the class to your image like so:

```
<img class="class" src="~/Content/Images/Battlefield1.jpg" alt=""/>
```

The other option is to change `.class` in the above CSS to `.portrait img` which would affect all images in the `portrait` div, of which is seems like you only want one to be there.

Comment: .portrait is the div. You need to set max-width on the image.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/86daf347188db82fe68c0c85d168f388 it messed up my image